# Are these \setlength, logical symbol \oplus, \nor,\nand compatible with IEEEtran?

Tags: ieeetran

Are these `\setlength`, logical symbol `\oplus`, `\nor`,`\nand` compatible with IEEEtran? 
 I searched and found one reference [here](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/tla/IEEEtran.sty) but there are too many different settings there which is confusing.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\nand}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\n@and@or\land}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\nor}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\n@and@or\lor}}

\newcommand{\n@and@or}[2]{%
  \vphantom{#2}%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1#2$\cr\hidewidth$\m@th#1\sim$\hidewidth\cr}%
}
%
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{12pt plus 3pt minus 9pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{12pt plus 3pt minus 9pt}%
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{12pt plus 3pt minus 9pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{7pt plus 3pt minus 4pt}%
\setlength{\jot}{3pt}% Inter-equation spacing
%
\begin{document}
$
A\oplus B\\
A\nor B \\
A\nand B
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "compatible with IEEEtran? " is not a technical question but a social one.  `\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{12pt plus 3pt minus 9pt}%` is globally changing the layout of the document. It won't error but the (human) editors of the journal may object to their design being changed and reject the submission.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, so what values should I set for these?

Comment: as a general rule for journal submissions, just provide words, the publishers provide the house style, so you should not be setting anything, but the exact rules will depend on the journal. Many jourals do not even use tex for the final form, so adding tex settings has no effect on the published form, and just complicate their internal production pipeline,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Aha, okay I'll remove it then. What do you mean by "not even use tex for the final form"? Do you mean they use Word instead of LaTeX? Also do you have any comment about the logical symbols above?

Comment: unlikely to use word but they may use APP (3b2)  or indesign etc (a recent question here, when a final pdf was shown showed it was APP, I forget which journal that was)

Comment: I see nothing that would clash with `IEEEtran` as far as `\nand` and `\nor` are concerned. Leave those `\setlength` instruction aside: you don't want to change the layout requested by the journal you're submitting to. As a copy editor I'd be annoyed (at best) by them.

Comment: You might check if other papers use this notation (for \nand and \nor) and inquire as to how it was done.  There is also The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List (CTAN), although I couldn't find anything similar.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a relational or an operator, so I gave it all. In addition, you should not try to modify any spacing of journal templates.

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\newcommand{\xxx}{\mathbin{\sim\mkern-18mu\land}}
\newcommand{\yyy}{\mathrel{\sim\mkern-18mu\land}}
\begin{document}
$A \xxx  B$ \par
$A \yyy  B$ \par
$A =     B$ \par
$A +     B$ \par
$A \land B$ \par
$A \sim  B$ \par
\end{document}
```

[image]